# What language is accepted by the following dfa (english)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

> [image: a DFA]

I feel like it accepts either the string {0}, or repeated {10} only. I tried making it have odd/even number of 0s and 1s but it still doesn't work. I know my answer is wrong but I really don't know how to read this one DFA.

(Sorry my english isn't good)

Comment: What are the accepting states? Those with a circle inside on the right?

Comment: How do you know your answer is supposedly wrong? A solution manual? Or some online resource ?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma because my teacher said so. He just rejected my answer but didn't give the correct one because this is an exercise (._.)

Comment: Maybe you had to explicitly say that we  have at least one $10$? How did you write your answer? was I right about the accepting states?

Comment: Since the question said in english, so I wrote "This DFA only accepts strings that are either: - only a single {0}, or - repetitions of {10} only." And yes, you're correct about the accepting states

Comment: Maybe you have to give the language in a regular expression not in natural language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the accepting states are the double circled ones:

$0$ moves us to an accepting state.
Anything after the initial $0$ will move us to the "central state" which is a black hole: we never leave and can no longer reach an accepting state anymore.

Downstairs it's more interesting: $11$ gets us to the black hole, so no accepted string can start with $11$, $10$ does bring is into an accepting state; after that we should have no $0$ but $10$ again to bring us back. $11$ is going to the black hole again.

So I get that $\{0\} \cup 10(10)\ast$ is the accepted language for this DFA.